# If TCP is a data stream, how do messages get created?

Tags: tcp, stream

Closest resemblance to my question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929711/sending-messages-in-a-tcp-stream).

However, I am still having troubles understanding how a TCP data stream creates "messages" if you will. Arn't messages things that happen after xx amount of time? A TCP stream is a constant flow of data.

For example, a game server running at 30hz. If messages are sent out at 30 times a second, they must be using something internally to do that, what is it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001434/async-tcp-server-message-framing-advice/16001812#16001812) answer may help a bit.

Comment: By the application. TCP doesn't have messages. It's up to application code to do that.

Comment: Buffer the stream and extract only complete messages.  You define what a complete message is (fixed length, terminated with nul or newline, write length then data, etc.)